# php short hand code. I dont understand how category_id is assigned the variable

Tags: php, html

Question :  I don't understand ?category_id=    is this short hand php?  if it is how would this be written so that it is not in short hand form ?

So for example:

```
<a href="?category_id=<?php echo $item['categoryID']; ?>"><?php echo $item['categoryName'] ?></a>
```

Comment: No, this is not PHP shorthand. If a `href` starts with a question mark, it will append it to the current page's URL. So if you're currently on http://example.com/page.php and `$item['categoryID']` is "123", that link will end up pointing to http://example.com/page.php?category_id=123

Answer (score 0):

It is not short hand php. The question mark `?` added to the URL creates a GET parameter `category_id` and equates it to whatever `$item['categoryID']` equals.